# Importing PC-lint report along with SonarQube C++ Commercial Plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-5.0, pc-lint

I would like to know if there is any way where we can integrate PC-lint report along with C++ analysis using Commercial C++ Plugin.
we are using SonarQube 5.1.2 currently.

But I am ready to upgrade if that's what it takes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SonarSource C++ Plugin, this means that you are a customer so you should contact the [commercial support](http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact/) who will answer your question.